# Cos'è una "pantàfeca"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita bianca come una **pantàfeca** s’affaccia dietro la tenda. Cosí, con lo stesso sguardo spiritato, l’ha vista quella notte. In piedi dietro al letto in fiamme, immobile – spettrale.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "pantàfeca"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo regionale, possibilmente correlato al napoletano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È una figura spettrale bianca tipicamente usata nelle superstizioni regionali.
Questo è un link con una descrizione adeguata, anche se il nome è leggermente diverso. Ma il concetto è lo stesso.
[Pandafeche](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandafeche)